# Issue with triggering SNS message from python3.6 Lambda function- TopicARN incorrect?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

My Lambda function is supposed to send a message to SNS once it's completed, and I'm using the below code to do it.  My TopicARN from the SNS topic is definitely the correct one, yet I am still getting the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in input: \"TopicARN\", must be one of: TopicArn, TargetArn, PhoneNumber, Message, Subject, MessageStructure, MessageAttributes",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
```

Can someone please review my code and let me know if I've done something wrong with the formatting here?  I can also tell you that I think have proper IAM role set up for the function to be able to:

IAM permissions:

```
{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:publish",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
```

Code Snippet:

```
def notify_when_bad(error_code, error_text):
        sns = boto3.client(service_name="sns")
        topicArn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:TopicName'

        if response.status_code == 200:
            sns.publish(
                TopicARN = (topicArn), 
                Message = (str("Instance ") + str(centreon_instance_name) + str("has been successfully removed from Centreon")))
        else:
            sns.publish(
                TopicArn = (topicArn), 
                Message = (str("Function failed with msg:") + str(error_text) + '\n' + str("Status Code:") + str(error_code)))
        return
    print(notify_when_bad(error_code, error_text))
```

Answer (score 3):

They compalin:

> `Unknown parameter in input: \"TopicARN\", must be one of: TopicArn,`

while you do

> ```
>         sns.publish(
>             TopicARN = (topicArn),
> ```

So, you name the parameter `TopicARN`, and they want `TopicArn`.

Yes, the parameters are case-sensitive.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't think bad of yourself; you are not your code.